# T4: Call external method that writes to the caller template

Tags: c#, .net, t4

I'm developing a framework based on T4, and I was wondering if there's a way to call a method (defined in a custom dll references by the T$ template) that writes to the caller template invocation.

I do realize that I could add a tag:
<#= CallMethodThatReturnsString #>

To the template and accomplish that, but users tend to forget the '=' sign, so I was wondering if there's a way to call a method with the standard <# #> directives and write programatically to that location.

Thanks

Comment: I'm a little unclear--are you trying to programmatically change your T4 template?  Can you give more context to the example you provided: `<#= CallMethodThatReturnsString #>` that shows what you want to do?  I know you don't want to use that method, but it may help demonstrate what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is.

Code generated from a T4 template inherits from [`Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TextTransformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.texttemplating.texttransformation.aspx) by default. This class has a `Write` method, which means these two directives are equivalent:

```
<#= Guid.NewGuid() #>
<# Write("{0}", Guid.NewGuid()); #>
```

You'd need to get a reference to `this` in order to be able to call `Write`. You could make some initialization mandatory for your lib, for instance:

```
<# MyLib.Initialize(this); #>
```

And then store this in a `static ThreadLocal<TextTransformation>` field.

But I see some problems with this approach:

- It obviously won't work if the user of your lib forgets to call `Ìnitialize`
- It won't work if the user of your lib wants to use a custom template base class which *does not* inherit from `TextTransformation`. You'd have to use `dynamic` to circumvent that
- Now, the `=` isn't required anymore, but you just traded that for a mandatory `;` at the end ;)

That being said, I wouldn't advise you to go this way - just don't bother and keep requiring the standard `<#= #>`.

... or, if feasible, you could write your own custom base class for the template and implement your lib in it. Just extend `TextTransformation` and use `<#@ template language="C#" inherits="MyLib" #>`